# Refering a page that called a particular page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, referer

I have an index page with three links as follws. When I click the first link (pageType1 in the example below), pageType1.php is run that first check if the user is logged in via cookie. If it is not then redirect the user to a login page. when a user submit  login and password info on login page correctly, I want to display the info on pageType1.php

FILE: index.php

```
<a href="pageType1.php" target="_blank">PageType1</a>
<a href="pageType2.php" target="_blank">PageType2</a>
<a href="pageType3.php" target="_blank">PageType3</a>
```

FILE : pageType1.php

```
<?php
include"auth/auth_check_header.php"; 
print("pageType1 contents");
?>
```

FILE : pageType2.php

```
<?php
include"auth/auth_check_header.php"; 
print("pageType2 contents");
?>
```

FILE : pageType3.php

```
<?php
include"auth/auth_check_header.php"; 
print("pageType3 contents");
?>
```

FILE : auth/auth_check_header.php

```
$successful_login_url = ??????   //How to track this value. 

if (!cookie_enabled)
    {
    //login page
    header("location:$successful_login_url");
    }
```

My question is how to track "$successful_login_url" value (Or what shoud I put as the value of this variable) in   auth/auth_check_header.php

Note: I tried putting $_SESSION["referer"] as the value of  "$successful_login_url" but it shows index.php after successful login. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) User try to access a pageType1.php

2) The user is redirected to the login.php which contains a form with the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirectTo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["HTTP_REFERER"]?>" />
```

3) User type the login and when successfully authenticated:

`$redirectTo = $_POST['redirectTo']`

4) If `$redirectTo` is not empty, then redirect, else redirect to a default page

Comment: Thanks Keyne, This approach worked for me to some extent but was very helpful and gave a clue on how to deal this problem.

Comment: @learner You're welcome. If you post a more detailed code (instead of snippets) I can show you how to properly apply it. Your code when checking the cookie is strange, you first check if the cookie is not set, and if not, you redirect to the success page? `header("location:$successful_login_url");`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the page url as a GET variable (query string) and redirect based on this or if you want to get the page the include is in, you can use 'PHP_SELF' and store this in a variable and use it to redirect back:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I tried putting $_SESSION["HTTP_REFERER"] as the value of "$successful_login_url" but it shows index.php after successful login.

Comment: Forget that, please. It will give the url from the page the url was requested. I've edited my answer with a solution.

Comment: somehow it is not helping me and it started giving me wrong username and password.

Comment: In this case, use the querystring method i've described above and Keyene detailed in his answer.